# Is it possible to archive logs based on size and on time using NLog

Tags: nlog

I am using `NLog`.

I would like to have a size-based file archival and a time-based file archival.

Meaning, every time the log file exceeds 10 MB a new log file is created. Also, every day a new log file is created.

It is clear how to do each of the above separately (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples) but not how to use them in tandem.

Comment: Can you give some example of how the filenames should be both when rolling on size and on date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any details of the expected fileName-Layout, then this will work just fine in NLog 4.5 (and newer):

```
<target type="file" name="logfile" fileName="App-${shortdate}.log" archiveAboveSize="1000000" maxArchiveFiles="30" />
```

It will produce the following filenames (newest first)

- App-20200216.log
- App-20200216.2.log
- App-20200216.1.log
- App-20200215.log
- App-20200214.log
- App-20200214.1.log

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files